# How can I write a range with vector on CPLEX?

Tags: vector, range, cplex

I have a problem with range.I I want to write a range where to scroll the variable i from 1 to nj. nj is a vector of n elements.

range I = 1..nj;

int nj [J] = ...;

nj = [1, 4, 5 , 6, 9, 3, 10];

How can I write this type of range on CPLEX? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int sizenj=7;

range I = 1..sizenj;

int nj [I] =  [1, 4, 5 , 6, 9, 3, 10];

execute
{
  writeln(nj);
}
```

works fine